# Sending a url data to another app through browser android

Tags: android

I have developed 2 android apps which I want to have an interconnection between each other. Let's say myapp and myapp123. I have implemented deeplink in myapp and the deeplink url is as `myapp://abcd/1;` What I want to do is by a click of a button in myapp123, I want to send a deeplink url to myapp which will launch my app and use that specific deeplink.

I have researched and found that I can send text data through an intent of myapp123 to catch through an intent in myapp but I cannot do any change t myapp. Therefore I have to find another solution.

So far what I have tried is that sending data to the browser as `myapp://abcd/1` so that browser will open the app as when deeplink works. But the problem I have is that to send data to browser, the schema must be `http` or `https` .

What I want to know is that whether there is a way I can send tht specific data to the browser without app being crashed so that it will open myapp.

I am new to android so I know I have missed something little here. It would be great if someone could point my mistake.

Comment: Did you pick this solution because you knew no other way to start myaapp through myapp123?

Comment: yes. Is there any? @Rüdiger

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

What you want to do is:

- Create a Intent in myapp123 and add the values you want to pass to this Intent
- Broadcast the created Intent
- Extend a BroadcastReceiver inside myapp and register it to it's Manifest
- Use the BroadcastReceiver from myapp to start your activity and read the values from the received Intent

Comment: Is there any way that I can avoid doing any changes to myapp and do changes only to myapp123 and get this done?